# Installation of R package `GeoXp` fails

Tags: r, install.packages, r-sp

I would like to install the package `GeoXp`, but R doesn't let me...see the error below...

```
>install.packages("GeoXp")
...
configure: using libpng dynamic linkage
checking for X... no
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/home/****/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rgl’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rgl’ is not available for package ‘GeoXp’
* removing ‘/home/******/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/GeoXp’

 Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘GeoXp’ had non-zero exit status   

The downloaded source packages are in 
   ‘/tmp/RtmpAbblyJ/downloaded_packages’

> library("GeoXp")
Error in library("GeoXp") : there is no package called ‘GeoXp’
```

Well, there seems to be a problem with the dependencies...but installing `rgl` does not work either...

Here my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
     LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8       
     LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                     
     LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C  
     LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods 
    base     

other attached packages:
[1] spacetime_1.1-3 sp_1.0-17      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.0.2       intervals_0.15.0 lattice_0.20-29 
    tools_3.0.2      xts_0.9-7        zoo_1.7-11
```

***What can I do?***

Comment: The headers of the X library are missing on your computer. You need to install them first. And you probably should do the same for gl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GeoXp` has a dependency on `rgl`, tries to install that first, but fails there. `rgl` needs to have the X11 development libraries, as well as the (open source) OpenGL development and run-time libraries (mesa). For Ubuntu, you need to install the system packages `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `libglu1-mesa-dev` first (with apt-get or sth similar), then install in R package `rgl`, then `GeoXp`.

Comment: I installed `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `libglu1-mesa-dev` via the Software Center in Ubuntu. Easy peasy. Now `GeoXp` does work, no need to install `rgl` first...thx @Edzer Pebesma

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have to install X library and gl

Ops, sorry @Pascal, I did not see your comment.